# How to hide columns? MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum, hide

I have a code I've made but I'd like to hide the column. So that it only shows the storeID instead of the SALARY along with it. I know I need to wrap it around in another set of brackets, but don't know where to do that. Also can anyone tell me a technique to identify where to use the brackets? Sorry, not too familiar with MySQL, but have been learning for couple of weeks now. Just finished the diagrams with Chen Notations, now the codes.

```
SELECT storeID, SUM(SALARY) FROM STORE
JOIN EMPLOYEE
WHERE SALARY < expenditure;
```

Currently it's displaying:

```
| storeID | |    SUM(SALARY)    |
|    1    | |    £30000         |
|    2    | |    £25000         |
|    3    | |    NOTHING        |
```

I want the second column SUM(SALARY) to be hidden. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I wasn't being too clear. I needed to calculate the SALARY (sum of all salaries from each store), and find the storeID's with SALARY < expenditure.

EMPLOYEE = SALARY
STORE = storeID and expenditure.

Comment: Can you explain what is this query supposed to do and provide definitions of STORE and EMPLOYEE tables? Where is "expenditure" taken from? I think that your query might do something else than you expect.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
SELECT StoreId
FROM
(
   SELECT storeID, SUM(SALARY) FROM STORE
   JOIN EMPLOYEE
   WHERE SALARY < expenditure
)
```

this should work ;)

Comment: Thanks very much, this is what I'm looking for! I just changed a bit and added an alias.

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
    SELECT storeID  FROM STORE
    JOIN EMPLOYEE
    WHERE SALARY < expenditure;
```

Comment: That nearly fulfills the requirements. I want to find total of all salaries in each store that has less salary than the expenditure. The code you provided just finds salary that's less than expenditure. I've edited my description, my fault for not being too clear in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you will need an Alias for this

```
SELECT x.name, x.branch
FROM (

SELECT person.name AS name, person.email, branch.name AS branch
FROM person
JOIN branch ON person.branch_id = branch.id
)x
```

So I name my query block with x, even you can reference by x like

```
x.name
x.branch
```